# How to achieve a color transition effect using jQuery's slideToggle() and CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-color, slidetoggle

How to achieve such an effect, using jQuery's slideToggle() and CSS, where the content that slides has a background-color that is connected to its clickable button with via the same color? I'm using Bootstrap.css for rows and columns. [image: please see image to visualize it better]

Source code: http://jsfiddle.net/azimbaig/37t6uzw0/1/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
    .first {
        /*position: fixed;
        left: 50%;
        top: 10%;
        transform: translate(-50%, 0);*/
        margin-left: 50%;
        margin-top: 10%;
        transform: translate(-50%);
    }
    .button {
        width: 200px;
        background-color: #EEE;
        margin-right: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }
    .hidden {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .lorem {
        display: none;
        background-color: #EEE;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
</style>
<div id="container">
    <div class="row first">
        <a href="#box1">
            <div id="btn_box1" class="col-md-4 button">
                <h1>Box #1</h1>
                <div></div>           
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#box2">
            <div id="btn_box2" class="col-md-4 button">
                <h1>Box #2</h1>
                <div></div>           
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#box3">
            <div id="btn_box3" class="col-md-4 button">
                <h1>Box #3</h1>
                <div></div>           
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="row content1">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div id="box1" class="col-md-8 lorem">
            <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row content2">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div id="box2" class="col-md-8 lorem">
            <h1>Google's Material Design</h1>
            <img src="https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7VG9DQVluOFJ4Tnc/materialdesign_principles_metaphor.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row content3">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div id="box3" class="col-md-8 lorem">
            <h1>Dummy text</h1>
            <p>Congue per sagittis semper vitae magna convallis consectetuer gravida cubilia. Orci nec Tincidunt Vestibulum phasellus aenean turpis nulla. Porta. Semper vel fermentum conubia vulputate dui. Sociis litora. Commodo iaculis.Molestie rutrum a viverra. Nam purus congue eleifend egestas et lobortis venenatis posuere. Magnis molestie. Tortor platea tellus velit mauris nostra rhoncus mauris adipiscing curabitur neque scelerisque aliquet facilisi sapien quisque vulputate varius nec. Aliquet augue feugiat taciti sit Lacus imperdiet. Litora parturient sed pellentesque, cubilia enim ad habitasse tortor Vehicula porta nascetur leo fringilla scelerisque sapien natoque sagittis elementum vel eu augue fringilla ipsum quam amet dapibus adipiscing sociis nulla.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $('#btn_box1').click(function(){
        $("#box1").slideToggle();
        $("#box2").hide();
        $("#box3").hide();
    });
    $('#btn_box2').click(function(){
        $("#box2").slideToggle();
        $("#box1").hide();
        $("#box3").hide();
    });  
    $('#btn_box3').click(function(){
        $("#box3").slideToggle();
        $("#box1").hide();
        $("#box2").hide();
    });  
});
</script>
```

Comment: Provide your source code.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 provided source code

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: @HarshSanghani added jsfiddle

Comment: something missing in your fiddle.

Comment: Its not showing as your image here.

Comment: @HarshSanghani my image is what I would like it to look like, more specifically I was wondering if you could help me achieve that connecting colored "bridge" between the Box button and the Content box using CSS. If you are talking about the layout of the box buttons then I'd advise you to full screen the Result window as they start to cascade on smaller windows.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your margin-top css from the lorem class like following :-

```
.lorem {
      display: none;
      background-color: #EEE;
}
```

It may help you.

Comment: It will remove that space between tab and content.